# Горизонтальная прокрутка не работает

Tags: css

Подскажите, почему в приведённой таблице не работает гор-я прокрутка?
А если для таблицы закомментировать ширину 900px, тогда начинает работать прокрутка.
https://jsfiddle.net/t44wyqb1/

```js
$('.icon').on('click', function(e){
 $('.row__content').slideToggle(500);
})
```

```css
ul{
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */
}
.table{
  /* width: 900px; */
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row-grid{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.row__content{
  display: none;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
}
.icon{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cell{
  width: 300px;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row__top row-grid">
          <div class="cell"><i class="icon"></i></div>
          <div class="cell">2</div>
          <div class="cell">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row__content row-grid">
          <div class="cell">content</div>
          <div class="cell">content2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Пробовали у `.table` сделать `overflow:scroll;`?

Comment: @Klimenkomud, пробовал конечно, результат тотже, как и с overflow: auto, прокрутка не работает

Comment: Очень странно, я на вашем jsfiddle попробовал раскоментить `width`, у меня прокрутка работает

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1dvbsLLu/

Comment: Может на самой странице что-то перебивает `overflow`?

Comment: @Klimenkomud, проверьте ещё раз, не работает прокрутка, т.е. прокрутку видно, но можно прокрутить только на пару пикселей, часть таблицы всё-равно скрыта!

Comment: Посмотрите еще раз, кинул в ответе ссылку, у вас просто контента было чуть больше чем 900 пикселей, вот и прокрутка была маленькая, почти ничего не выпадало из контейнера)

Answer (score 0):

Прокрутка появится если места под контент не хватает. В вашем же случае все элементы равномерно растягиваются и место для них есть. Уменьшите ширину экрана или `<ul>` и увидите.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ширина таблицы `900px` и 3 столбца по `300px` с бордерами по `2px`, вот и прокрутка маленькая. Если увеличить количество столбцов или их размер - прокрутка появится.
https://jsfiddle.net/1dvbsLLu/

```js
$('.icon').on('click', function(e){
 $('.row__content').slideToggle(500);
})
```

```css
ul{
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li{
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */
}
.table{
  width: 900px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row-grid{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.row__content{
  display: none;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
}
.icon{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cell{
  width: 400px;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row__top row-grid">
          <div class="cell"><i class="icon"></i></div>
          <div class="cell">2</div>
          <div class="cell">3</div>
          <div class="cell">4</div>
          <div class="cell">5</div>
          <div class="cell">6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row__content row-grid">
          <div class="cell">content</div>
          <div class="cell">content2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: та хоть 10 столбцов, последний всё-равно не видно https://jsfiddle.net/1dvbsLLu/1/

Comment: @word https://jsfiddle.net/1dvbsLLu/2/ подвиньте немного панель с html и js

Comment: >подвиньте немного панель с html и js

Comment: это как можно подвинуть панель html вместе с js?

Comment: На бордер наведите, курсор станет соответствующим

Comment: @word Вы до сих пор не видите корректной прокрутки?

Comment: при чём здесь бордер до курсора?

Comment: @word Прокручивайте окно выполнения кода, и вы заметите, что прокрутка есть и столбцы не обрезаются.

Answer (score -1):

А с чего вы решили что не работает? У вас что профессиональная игровая мышка с двумя и больше скроллами, и один из них не срабатывает ? * Лично у меня ваш пример работает - Попадаем в область скролла, зажимаем на клавиатуре клавишу `Shift` и вот мы уже можем скроллом миши гонять горизонтальный скролл таблицы.

То что вы думаете, что горизонтальный скролл вам обязан что-то делать функционалом которым он ничего не назначен. Это не так.